# update and using sum to calculate column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am using sql-server. I have a table which contains the value of a list of companies. I wish to workout the % of each company as part of this list. See example below

```
name   value    wgt%
abc    10
plm    15
xyz    25
```

So above is what I have, below is what I would like,

```
name   value    wgt%
abc    10       20
plm    15       30
xyz    25       50
```

I tried something like:

```
update D_COMP_VALUES
set wgt = value / sum(value)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: sorry should have specified that - I am using sql server

Comment: the way I would do it is load the data you need into a temp table or table variable, then do an update on a join of the temp/variable table to the base table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub-select to get the total sum:

```
update D_COMP_VALUES
set wgt = 100 * value / (select sum(value) from D_COMP_VALUES)
```

But it's normally a bad idea to store computed values. Create a view instead, that never will have inconsistent data!

Comment: I would suggest to use `100.0` to handle decimal value

Comment: @ShantanuGupta, could of course be done, but the expected result has no decimals.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using window functions:

```
with toupdate as
      select cv.*, sum(value) over () as sumvalue
      from d_comp_values
     )
update toupdate
    set wgt = value / sumvalue;
```

Note that SQL Server does integer division, so if `value` is an integer (as suggested by your sample data), you will probably get zero unless you convert to another numeric representation:

```
set wgt = value * 1.0 / sumvalue;
```

Answer (score 1):

An update-join seems in order:

```
UPDATE     d
SET        wgt = value * 100.0 / sumvalue 
FROM       d_comp_values d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(value) AS sumvalue FROM d_comp_values) agg
```

Comment: don't forget to set wgt *100 to get a percentage instead of decimal

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple update:

```
UPDATE D_COMP_VALUES
SET wgt = value * 100 / (SELECT SUM(value) FROM D_COMP_VALUES)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f48f/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the implementation to you, but here's the way I would do this.

1. Create a variable for the sum.
2. Calculate the sum from a query and insert it into the variable
3. Update the base table setting wgt = value/variable

That said, storing this information in the table is a bad idea, and you should be calculating it or using a view.